# How to release this accuride drawer slide?

Tags: drawers

I have tried everything, and looked all over the web.
This slide lacks release levers that I can find/see!
Other than unscrewing the plate from the drawer, is there a way to get teh drawer out?

I have tried:

- pulling hard (nope, it is a hard stop)
- lifting it out
- searching for a release

[image: accuride drawer slide]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You push the black tab in to towards the side of the drawer. Then lift up the front edge, making sure the black tab fits through the slot. Once the black tab is clear, you can pull the drawer out a tiny bit to unhook the hook towards the back.

[image]

Comment: All it took was that photo with a little red circle around the culprit. Couldn't get it sorted from all of the "written" clues. Thanks a million!